# Hiding the emacs tex-shell

Tags: emacs, latex, pdflatex

is there a simple way to make emacs put the tex-shell output in a background buffer? i.e.  as opposed to the default behavior where it automatically makes split window to show the tex-shell.

More often than not I do not need to see the tex-shell output after rendering and it just unnecessarily takes up window space which I have to fix (an admittedly minor annoyance but an annoyance nevertheless).

Thank you

Comment: There's actually a StackExchange site for TeX here: tex.stackexchange.com .

Comment: I know, but I thought this was more of an emacs question.

Comment: Well, if it was a plain old Emacs question, it would belong on superuser.com ; stackoverflow is for coding problems.

Comment: As there is no solution yet, I guess it will require lisp coding. So yes, it belongs to so.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [AUCTeX](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/) (it's much better than the builtin tex-mode) which will only open the TeX shell if you ask it to.